# Probable comment vote bug in late answer review list

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

When reviewing a late answer, I scrolled down to check the question, to get some context. This question had a lot of comments, and the `show x more comments` link was available. This of course lead to the entire comment list of the question being shown. But it also allowed me to up-vote a comment in that list. Which led to the `I'm Done` button getting activated.

In case the question's entire comment list is already visible (i.e. the `show x more comments` link is not available), voting on comments is not allowed.

Isn't this a bug? If I'm reviewing a late answer, why should a vote on a comment in the question be counted as reviewed?

[Sample post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/715651)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reviewing an *answer*, voting up a comment on the *question* no longer enables the "I'm Done" button. Good catch.